# Can Parquet file format index string columns?

Tags: parquet

I know that the Parquet format keeps min/max statistics for integer columns.

In this way a query can directly skip several column chunk pages when they are not relevant. For example if a chunk only contains the range `[1, 5]` and the query asks for number `> 10` you can skip that group of rows without loading it.

1. Are there such optimizations for a string column (e.g. a country name)?
2. Are there such optimizations for a long text (e.g. a blog post) where you need to search some keywords?

Basically I would like to understand if Parquet adds performance benefits only for numeric data or if it adds performance gains also on string search.